# Using MS Access and VBA to generate Ms Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

this is the first time I coding VBA. I need to generate a Word Doc using the data in my database (Selected Tables Only). I managed to create the Word Doc with some text inside the document using `XXX.Selection.TypeText`. However I can't figure out how to include the Header and Footer for the report. I tried many ways and I can't get the results i wanted.

My question is, it is possible for me to use/open a prefined word document (with Headers and Foots) and populated my data inside that prefined word document?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to print data into a ready-made document you could try setting bookmarks [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221387(v=office.11).aspx]

Comment: You can use either use a template with headers and footers and update the text or you can create the headers and footers from scratch using VBA. Try to record a macro of what you want to do in Word, then modify it to suit your needs and transfer the code to Access.

Comment: I agree with Ollie - if you really want to do it all in code, record a macro in Word and move it over.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look on the following code:

this will create a new word document including header and footer content as well as body content.

**NOTE:** Don't forget to add reference for Microsoft Word Object

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim WordHeaderFooter As HeaderFooter

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With objWord
    .Visible = True

    Set doc = .Documents.Add
    doc.SaveAs CurrentProject.Path & "\TestDoc.doc" 
End With

With objWord.Selection

 .Font.Name = "Trebuchet MS"
 .Font.Size = 16

  .TypeText "Here is an example test line, #" & " - Font size is " & .Font.Size
  .TypeParagraph

    'Add header and footer

    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header"
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Footer"
End With

doc.Save
doc.Activate
```

[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) [ms-word](/questions/tagged/ms-word)